# neo4j dump error: database does not exist

Tags: neo4j

I'm new to neo4j.

I have created a new graph/database named `db-learning`. I'm able to connect and perform some operations on the database via neo4j browser. No issue at all.

However when I tried to dump it using `neo4j-admin dump --database "db-learning" --to "/some/path"` I get this error saying database not found.

> Database does not exist: db-learning

[image]

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry if that's confusing. The database name in the project is not related to the underlying database name (which is `neo4j` for the default database)

So if you open the terminal, this should be good enough:

`./bin/neo4j-admin dump --database "neo4j" --to "/tmp/test.dump"`

I think you can also leave off the default database name.

Comment: The dump and restore process is very confusing right now.  Would be good to have a button in the Neo4j Desktop app to just dump / restore.

Comment: The dump and restore is honestly a nightmare. Why can't we dump a remote DB? The errors when versions are mis-aligned are super confusing, "Database does not exist: neo4j" when it in fact exists.

Comment: Hi @Michael Hunger, could you please clarify ?

I tried `./bin/neo4j-admin dump --database="neo4j" --to=/dumps/neo4j/neo4j-20220524.dump` but message still `Database does not exist: neo4j`. I also tried with out the --database flag. 

Which is the advised simplest procedure for dumping (and reloading) a db ?
Or do you suggest using apoc procedures? 

https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/backup-restore/restore-dump/

Answer (score 2):

Getting the same issue when neo4j is in fact an existing DB. I don't know how the N4J team managed to overcomplicate this so much but this whole process is such a nightmare.

The Aura service only accepts .dump files, which have to be generated via neo4j-admin. This won't allow remote DBs so you have to pull down a neo4j directory (for instance, from a graphenedb.com dump), load it locally, then export that via neo4j-admin -> dump file in order to upload and import into a Aura instance.

Has anyone at Neo4j actually used their own software?